# sql server macro

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to add and update a number of columns(P_1,P_2,P_3...) in sequence to a table. To update P_2 I need P_1 to be updated in a previous step. Is there a way to write a loop which can do this in **SSMS**

```
for i in (1 to 10)
     alter table tab1 add P_i
     if(i>1)
          update tab1 set P_i = P_(i-1)*2+[blah blah]
     else
          update tab1 set p_i = [blah blah]
     end
end
```

Comment: Why are you doing this?  We don't usually treat table structure this way.  First define the table with all the columns you're going to need.  Then write T/SQL blocks or procedures using , e.g., WHILE.

Comment: Rereading the OP, I would agree with criticalfix that you probably don't want to create dynamic table structures. I missed that you were trying to add columns conditionally. If at all possible, create a fixed table structure; it's better database design.

Comment: You can do it with a cursor and [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) but a more important question is *why* you want to do this. Dynamically generated data models are not always a bad thing if you're using appropriate tools to generate and manage them (usually some kind of ORM). But generating table structures in this way is very unusual: how will the rest of your code know what the columns are called when it needs to use them in a query?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Here's an example of some conditional logic you can execute from within SSMS. This shows you how to perform a WHILE loop, an IF/THEN statement, and a CASE statement. HTH.

```
-- DROP TABLE dbo.Test
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test ( myID INT );

DECLARE @iteration INT = 0;

WHILE @iteration < 10
BEGIN
    IF @iteration = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES (-1);
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Test
        SET myID = CASE 
                    WHEN @iteration = 1 THEN 0 
                    WHEN @iteration = 2 THEN 123
                    ELSE @iteration 
                   END;
    END;

    SELECT * FROM dbo.Test;

    SET @iteration += 1;
END;
```